# Vim: What does apostrophe (') or backtick (`) followed by a digit do

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I was trying to learn [how to use marks in Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks), and accidentally hit a digit instead of a letter after hitting a backtick. As a result a file I edited a few days ago opened in the current buffer. Hitting other digits opened other recently edited files, but not in any particular order. Additionally, closing and reopening `Vim` further reshuffles the order. Can anyone explain what it does and how to use this feature?

Comment: Did you reference the help in Vim?

Comment: I was trying to, yes, but I am not sure how I can reference the help knowing only the key sequence that triggers the action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

numbered marks were set in `.viminfo` file, you cannot set it directly. Vim's Help doc has explained how it worked:

```
Numbered marks '0 to '9 are quite different.  They can not be set directly.
They are only present when using a viminfo file |viminfo-file|.  Basically '0
is the location of the cursor when you last exited Vim, '1 the last but one
time, etc.  Use the "r" flag in 'viminfo' to specify files for which no
Numbered mark should be stored.  See |viminfo-file-marks
```

and:

```
Uppercase marks ('A to 'Z) are stored when writing the viminfo file.  The
numbered marks ('0 to '9) are a bit special.  When the viminfo file is written
(when exiting or with the ":wviminfo" command), '0 is set to the current cursor
position and file.  The old '0 is moved to '1, '1 to '2, etc.  This
resembles what happens with the "1 to "9 delete registers.  If the current
cursor position is already present in '0 to '9, it is moved to '0, to avoid
having the same position twice.  The result is that with "'0", you can jump
back to the file and line where you exited Vim.
```

Comment: I'm still a little lost after reading this answer. Could you clarify how backticks play into this? Thanks!

Comment: Quote from the article OP referenced: To jump to a mark enter an apostrophe (`'`) or backtick (`\``) followed by a letter. Using an apostrophe jumps to the beginning of the line holding the mark, **while a backtick jumps to the line and column of the mark**.

Answer (score 3):

It's all in the help. Starting with `:help marks`, after the related commands, there's a section on what marks are, listing:

> '0 - '9       numbered marks, set from .viminfo file

There's more information further down:

> Numbered marks '0 to '9 are quite different.  They can not be set directly.
>   They are only present when using a viminfo file |viminfo-file|.  Basically '0
>   is the location of the cursor when you last exited Vim, '1 the last but one
>   time, etc.  Use the "r" flag in 'viminfo' to specify files for which no
>   Numbered mark should be stored.  See |viminfo-file-marks|.